# criar um formulario mult model usando nested-form e devise (sign up)

Tags: devise

eu preciso criar um formulario de cadastro usando o formulario de sign up do devise e associando a ele um model custumer que contem informações como nome, data de nascimento etc. como faço para executar o nested attribute no devise?

Answer (score 0):

Deve ser parecido com isso:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
    user_params.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```